# Losing data while inserting in clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I want to insert data from one table to another. I use no filters except of date so my query look as follows:

```
insert into table1
    select *
    from table2
    where dt = 'yyy-mm-dd'
```

But I lose some data in this insert.

For example if table2 has 5 rows with some ID, in the table1 I see only 1 or 2 rows with that ID.

Table2 is `ReplicatedMergeTree`, and table1 is `ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree`

Comment: hi marc_s - clearly, this type of query shouldn't be losing data, but a couple things to check: (1) since table1 is ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree, are you sure the "missing" data was not duplicated in table1? Could run "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE dt = 'yyyy-mm-dd' FINAL"; to confirm (I'm assuming "yyy" was just a typo); and (2) were there any errors on the output of the above INSERT command?

Comment: Please, edit your question with `table1` ddl.